# Why am I seeing localhost:8000 empty path does not match Django?

Tags: python, django, url-pattern

I keep running into 'Page not found' when trying to load http://localhost:8000/ . I have an empty path set to direct the page to my `project_index` page, but this is all I get:

[image]

I have checked and re-checked all of my `urlpatters`, but cannot figure out where the problem is.

Here are all my `urls.py` scripts that correspond to this project:

personal_portfolio/:
[image: personal_portfolio/urls.py]

projects/:
[image: projects/urls.py]

blog/:
[image: blog/urls.py]

Comment: "I have an empty path set to direct the page to my project_index page" inside projects app, and then you mount projects app urls at `projects/`, which makes your `project_index` url be served at `projects/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have anything starting with

```
urlpatterns = [
          path("", ..... ),
]
```

in your main `urls.py.`

like all the `URLs` you defined has a suffix thus Django can't find it,

either you need to do

```
urlpatterns = [
          path("", include('project.urls') ),
]
```

or

```
urlpatterns = [
          path("", include('blog.urls') ),
]
```